# Evaluating Summation of $5^{-n}$ from $n=4$ to infinity

Tags: summation

The answer is $\frac1{500}$ but I don't understand why that is so.

I am given the fact that the summation of $x^{n}$ from $n=0$ to infinity is $\frac1{1-x}$. So if that's the case then I have that $x=\frac15$ and plugging in the values I have $\frac1{1-(\frac15)}= \frac54$.

Comment: The sum you are asked to compute is from $n=4$ to infinity, but your formula computes the sum from $n=0$ to infinity.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}5^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^{-n-4}$

Comment: @Bungo Thank you for your response. I understand that's the case, but the formula that is given does not include an n. How do I incorporate this into the formula? Thank you.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you for your response. I understand that's the case, but the formula that is given does not include an n. How do I incorporate this into the formula? Thank you. –  kelly just now   edit

Comment: I assume the formula you are referring to is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = 1/(1-x)$, provided that $|x| < 1$. In order to apply this formula, you need to maneuver your sum $\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}5^{-n}$ into a sum starting at $n=0$. My hint should get you started.

Comment: @Kelly The formula you are using is valid $n=0$ to $\infty$. However, you are not interested in the first four iterations, even though they are added into your result of $\frac{5}{4}$. So if you've added four things you dont want, how might you get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you do not know why the formula works to begin with. If you did the situation would be clear. Here's the thing:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r} \; \;\;\;\;\; |r|<1.$$

Let $r=\frac{1}{5}$, then you really have the following situation:

$$\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^0+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^1+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5+....$$
Let's call this infinite sum $S$ and proceed as follows,

$$S=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^0+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^1+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5+....$$
then 
$$ \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)S=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^1+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^6....\;\;\;\;$$

Subtract the second from the first,

$$S-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)S=1$$
$$S(1-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right))=1$$
$$S=\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)}$$
$$S=\frac{5}{4}.$$

Now recall what $S$ was and realize,
$$S=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^0+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^1+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5+....=\frac{5}{4}$$
But, you want the powers to start at $n=4$, so subtract the first 4 powers(0,1,2,3) to get,
$$S-\left(1+\frac{1}{5}+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3\right)$$
which means 
$$\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5+....=\frac{5}{4}-\left(1+\frac{1}{5}+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3\right)=\frac{1}{500}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The formula gives from $n=0$ to infinity, but you are asked to sum from $n=4$ to infinity. In this case, you take the terms from $n=0$ to infinity using the formula (which you determined is $\frac54$), and get rid of the extra terms. In this case, we don't need the terms when $n=0,1,2,3$, so we can get rid of those terms by subtracting them. The sum is then $\frac54-5^{-0}-5^{-1}-5^{-2}-5^{-3}=\frac1{500}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{1}{5^n}=\frac{1}{5^4}\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{n-4}}=\frac{1}{5^4}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^m}=\frac{1}{5^4}\frac{1}{1-1/5}=\frac{1}{500}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n = (1/5)^4+...+(1/5)^n\ \ \ \ \ (i)$$

$$-(1/5)S_n = -(1/5)^5-...-(1/5)^n-(1/5)^{n+1}\ \ \ \ (ii)$$

$(i)+(ii)$ $$S_n(1-1/5) = (1/5)^4 - (1/5)^{n+1} \Rightarrow (4/5)S_n = 1/625 - (1/5)^{n+1}$$

$\Rightarrow S_n = 1/500 - (5/4)(1/5)^{n+1}$

but

$(1/5)^n \rightarrow 0$